# How to programmatically generate Slot expressions for the function in FormFunction?

Tags: slot, form-building

I am making a FormFunction expression programmatically, based on external lists of questions and possible answers. Here is a toy example:

```
qList={"Question 1","Question 2","Question 3","Question 4"};

answerChoices={"Strongly agree","Neutral","Strongly Disagree"};
```

Here is an example that works to return the responses from the form, in which the first argument to `FormFunction` (the form itself) is programmatic, but the function (`Print`) is handwritten using `Slot` notation:

```
FormFunction[
  MapIndexed[{"a" <> ToString[#2[[1]]], #1} -> <|
      "Interpreter" -> answerChoices, "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|> &,
    qList], Print[{#a1, #a2, #a3, #a4}] &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Lecture 1 questions", 
    "ItemLayout" -> "Vertical"|>][]
```

Here is an example of an output:

```
{Strongly Disagree,Strongly agree,Neutral,Strongly agree}
```

But I can't figure out how to generate the *function* programmatically. I tried this

```
slotList = Table[ToExpression["#\"a"<>ToString[fact]<>"\""],{fact,1,Length[qList]}]
```

which generates an expression that *looks* exactly like my hand-coded version, but when I use it

```
FormFunction[
  MapIndexed[{"a" <> ToString[#2[[1]]], #1} -> <|
      "Interpreter" -> answerChoices, "Control" -> RadioButtonBar|> &,
    qList], Print[slotList] &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "Lecture 1 questions", 
    "ItemLayout" -> "Vertical"|>][]
```

all it does is print the `slotList` expression

```
{#a1,#a2,#a3,#a4}
```

Comment: Why not just define a function `f[x__] := Print[List[x]]` then put `f` there in place of the `Print[slotList]&`. e.g that will look like `... qList], f, AppearanceRules -> ...`. Note the __ allows x to be a sequence of expressions. Obviously choose a better name than `f` for readability's sake.

Comment: That works! At least roughly: what is submitted to `f` is the full association, but that's fine for my purposes (I'm actually submitting the responses to a Databin).

Comment: But I would still like to know why the programmatic version of the Slot notation *doesn't* work.  ;)

Comment: It's just an evaluation order problem I believe. Compare `ToExpression["#^2"] &[3]` which returns `#1^2`, with `ToExpression["#^2&"][3]` which returns `9`. You can actually get the first one to work, but you need to force the evaluation order with `(Evaluate[ToExpression["#^2"]] &)[3]`. You could have solved your problem by just adding an evaluate, but it's much nicer to use sequences than constructing symbols with `ToString`.